# Can't configure tkinter object Listbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I run this code to create a Listbox and change its appearance, I am given the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'":

```
listbox = Listbox(myscreen).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW, rowspan=2)
listbox.config(border=2, relief=SUNKEN)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the listbox before placing it.

```
listbox = Listbox(myscreen)
listbox.config(border=2, relief=SUNKEN)
listbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW, rowsoan=2)
```